# Math result in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

Here I calculate number Of lines. If I have numberOflines with float value, like 1,2; 1,234, 4,56 I want to increase numberOflines, How can I detect it ?

```
    CGFloat numberOflines = (dataCount - 5) / 4.0;
```

numberOflines - numberOflines in collection

dataCount - number of items in collection

5 - first row have 1 item, all other row have 4. 4+1 = 5

I want detect how many row I will have

Comment: What is dataCount? What do you want to detect? Whether or not numberOfLines is equal to 1.2?  What are you getting? What are you expecting? What have you tried?

Comment: FYI - Since you are dividing an integer by 4, your results can only end with .0, .25, .5, or .75.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat numberOflines = ceilf(((float)dataCount - 5.0f) / 4.0f);
```

Comment: There's no need to cast `dataCount` to `float`.

Comment: @rmaddy you're correct that the casting isn't necessary, however some people prefer explicit type conversions to relying on implicit ones.